# Envió de Correo Automático

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quisiera saber porque no me funciona este script estoy utilizando `MailApp.sendEmail()` dentro del activador `onEdit`, lo que trato de hacer es que al cambiar un valor en una columna en especifico se envié un correo automático dependiendo del valor que se coloco en esa celda, pero por alguna razón no lo envía, ya lo ejecute desde editor de secuencias y ahí si lo envía pero al cambiar el valor en la celda solamente me muestra la ventana de diálogo.

```js
    function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var col = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
if(col == 6){
  var dato = ss.getActiveRange().getValue() 
  if(dato == 'Aprobado'){
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert(
     'Alerta',
     '¿Desea enviar correo de confirmacion?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
            var mail = ss.getActiveRange(row,1).Value();
            MailApp.sendEmail(mail, "Salas de Reuniones", "Confirmacion de reserva de salas de Reunion");
            ui.alert('Se envio correo de de confirmacion.');
          }
          else {
                ui.alert('No se envio correo de confirmacion');
               }
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. La respuesta del `SI` o del `NO` la estás recogiendo en una variable que se llama `response`, pero luego para comparar usas otra variable : `if (result == ui.Button.YES) {` , por tanto, debes usar la variable (`response`) que recogió la respuesta del botón: **`if (response == ui.Button.YES) {`**

Comment: Realmente tenia ese error en mi código, sin embargo lo he corregido y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ¿Pero qué hace el código, muestra algo, no muestra nada? ¿Revisaste en el log de GAS si marca algún error?

Comment: Este es el mensaje que me aparece en el log 
[19-02-11 19:29:16:464 CST] Error de ejecución: No tienes permisos para llamar a MailApp.sendEmail. Estos son los permisos necesarios: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail (línea 15, archivo "Código") [2.762 segundos de tiempo de ejecución total]

Comment: ¿Estás logueado con tu cuenta de Google cuando intentas hacer eso? Debes otorgar los permisos que te solicite o revisar si no has denegado sin darte cuenta el permiso para que Sheets use el envío de mensajes.

Comment: Si me encuentro logado en mi cuenta, encontré esta información en la documentación de GAS, al parecer hay una forma de generar los permisos pero me es difícil comprender para mi esto pues soy un poco novato, tal vez tu puedas entenderlo mejor que yo.    https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-authorization#editor_add-on_authorization

Comment: Puedes enviar máximo 500 correos diarios usando Google Sheets. Te lo digo por experiencia. ¿Estás seguro que quieres ir por una solución con Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los activadores simples como onEdit no pueden ejecutar servicios como MailApp que requiren autorización pero los activadores instalables si lo pueden hacer.

Para usar un activador instalable,

1. Lo primero es cambiar el nombre de tu funicón onEdit pues este es un nombre reservado para el activador simple.
2. Luego crea el activador instalable haciendo clic en Editar > Activadores del proyecto activo. Se mostrará la página de activadores del proyecto activo.
3. Luego haz clic en el botón "+ Añadir activador".
4. Completa el formulario mostrado y haz clic en el botón Guardar.

NOTA: Te sugiero modificar la configuración del envío de notificaciones de errores de cada día a inmediatamente durante la etapa de desarrollo.